# Need help getting through the LiftWeb Getting Started tutorial

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to get through the [LiftWeb Getting Started Tutorial](http://liftweb.net/getting_started).

This is what I've done:

1. Downloaded and unpacked the [tar-file](https://github.com/lift/lift_22_sbt/tarball/2.2).
2. (Here I tried to do `sbt update` as stated in the instructions, but it failed.)
3. Copied `lift_blank/*` to project root.
4. Then `sbt update` (successfully this time)
5. Copied the source code for *Chat.scala* and inserted the tag in *webapp/index.html* as instructed.
6. Executed `sbt ~jetty-run`
7. Opened a http://localhost:8080 in a browser.

But all I see is this:

[image]

which doesn't look like a chat-application to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried it my self and I must say that the tutorial isn't very clear about where to paste the div block.

Here's what I did in addition to the instructions on the tutorial page:

I pasted the given div snippet into the existing main div block of the index.html.

```
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">

<div class="lift:comet?type=Chat">
  <ul>
    <li>line</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

This should do it.

After running jetty, I could use the simple chat app.

Here's a screen shot of what I am seeing after running `sbt ~jetty-run`
[image: lift_basic]

Hope that helps
Thomas

Btw, it even works with lift_blank:
[image: lift_blank]

Comment: The tutorial has now been updated to specify that the snippet should live inside div#main.